# Thunderbird send later [to:email address], unless new email from 'email address'

Tags: email, thunderbird, delay, sendmail

I'm using jikamens' [Send Later 4.1.6](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/) plugin for Thunderbird 17.0.3 (for Mac) and I am looking for a smart way to add an additional parameter to the *send later* command.

I would like to ad the condition that the *send later* be canceled - with a notice - if I in-between having written my email and stored it to be *send later* receive an email from this particular person.

Say I get and email from x and I reply with a 3 days delay using the *send later*, after 48 hours I receive an new email from x that I do not see or reply to before my initial *send later* email is sent.

Is there a solution to this? I would also be willing to consider alternative email software.

Comment: I have no idea, but I would recommend looking into additional plugins or rules for incoming mail to match up the email address of the inbound to the outbound and delete on a match rather than somehow adjusting 'send later'

Comment: @Simkill, thank you for commenting on my question and thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I got an alternative for you. Schedulemailer sends your emails directly at your chosen point in the future. Here's the link: https://www.schedulemailer.com/en/send-email-later and there's also a video on youtube: http://youtu.be/06NbX86ocLE Hope I could help you!

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I'm not sure what I get by using [Schedulemailer](https://www.schedulemailer.com/en/send-email-later) that I don't have by using [Send Later 4.1.6](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/) plugin. Could you expand on your answer?